Error in Visual Studio when trying to use threads using pthreas
I get a C2011 error each time i try executing despite having the library installed. This was the video I follow along for install.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void* PrintHello(void* data) {
    int my_data = (int)data;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    printf("ehllo from new thread - got %d\n", my_data);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int rv;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int t = 11;

    rv = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)t);
    if (rv) {
        printf("\n Error: pthread_create error code is %d \n", rv);
        exit(1);}

    printf("\n Created new thread (%u) ... \n", thread_id);
    pthread_exit(NULL);}

Tried using the answers from this post but those didn't work either.

..or switch to a POSIX environment. You could install WSL as a good enough replacement of a Linux box

Please provide the error message you are asking about!

@Someprogrammerdude There's always been Windows ports for pthreads, hence this question about how to install such a lib.

Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build log (as text). And also please tell us all settings you have changed in the project.
